# Crear PDF desde una matriz de octetos en Angular

Tags: angular, pdf, angular10

Tengo un servicio API que me está devolviendo una matriz de octetos.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo convertir esto en un documento PDF y, a su vez, generar una vista previa de éste mismo dentro de mi componente.

Agradezco quien me pueda ayudar. Soy nuevo en Angular. Estoy usando Angular 10.

[image: Captura de los datos recibidos]

Tengo una variable con esos octetos, pero lo debo convertir a PDF, agradezco quien me pueda ayudar por favor.

---

El componente donde tengo la llamada es:

```
var facturaImpresa = this.impresionFacturaService.ImprimirFactura(this.envioImpresion).subscribe(res => {
  if(res){
    this.facturaDocumento = '';
    respuestaImpresion = res;
    for(let registro of respuestaImpresion){
      this.facturaDocumento = this.facturaDocumento + registro.LINE
    }
    /* this.facturaDocumento = respuestaImpresion; */

    var file = new Blob([this.facturaDocumento], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
    debugger;            
  }
});
```

El servicio donde hago la llamada es:

```
ImprimirFactura(cabData:imprimirFacturaModel):Observable<any>{
    return this.http
    .post<any>(`${environment.API_URL}${environment.ApiImprimirFactura}`,cabData )
    .pipe(      
      map((res:any) => {
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
    )
  }
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que eso es una matriz de octetos (*byte array*)? Más bien parecen datos binarios codificados en hexadecimal.

Comment: Por lo pronto cerramos la pregunta por no tener suficiente información para resolverla. Por favor, edita tu pregunta [pulsando aquí o en el enlace "Editar"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/480153/edit) y procederemos a reabrirla cuando tengamos datos suficientes para resolverla.

Comment: Te agradezco tu comentario y pido ayuda para saber si alguien sabe como convertir estos datos a PDF

Comment: Convertir esos datos a PDF es sencillo, o al menos sé hacerlo con javascript sencillo. Pero para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si no nos muestras el código de tu servicio o, al menos, del componente, poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: claro que si mira te adjunto mi servicio es este donde recibo como tal la variable con los datos que puse en el enunciado
ImprimirFactura(cabData:imprimirFacturaModel):Observable<any>{
    return this.http
    .post<any>(`${environment.API_URL}${environment.ApiImprimirFactura}`,cabData )
    .pipe(      
      map((res:any) => {
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
    )
  }

Comment: Por favor, tal y como te indiqué en mi comentario anterior, edita tu pregunta para agregar código en ella. Los comentarios no son un lugar adecuado para esa tarea.

Comment: vale pregunta editada

Comment: Solo quedaría que confirmaras el formato en el que te llega el contenido del archivo, ya que eso que muestras no es una cadena binaria, si no que aparenta ser una cadena continua de cifras hexadecimales.

Comment: lo unico que te puedo decir es que es en bite, pero la respuesta llega codificada, por eso se ve asi

Comment: La cadena empieza por `255044462D312E310A`. Son los caracteres hexadecimales que forman `%PDF-1.1\n`, por lo que asumo que se te entrega una cadena de caracteres con los datos en hexadecimal. La conversión es prácticamente trivial. En cuanto se reabra la pregunta redacto la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La cadena de caracteres que muestras en tu pregunta empieza por `255044462D312E310A`, que se corresponden con los caracteres hexadecimales de la cadena `%PDF-1.1\n`, por lo que entiendo que tu API te entrega una cadena de caracteres con los datos en hexadecimal.

La conversión puede hacerse de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Encapsulamos la funcionalidad en una clase */
class DecodificarHexa {
    constructor (datosHexa, tipoMime = "application/force-download") {
        /* Dividimos la cadena en parejas de caracteres hexadecimales */
        const parejas = datosHexa.match(/.{1,2}/g);
        /* Convertimos cada pareja hexadecimal en un carácter */
        const octetos = parejas.map(
            c => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16))
        );
        /* Unimos los caracteres en una única cadena de caracteres */
        const archivo = octetos.join("");
        /* Creamos un Blob con los datos proporcionados */
        this.blob = new Blob(
            [ archivo ],
            { type: tipoMime }
        );
        /* Creamos una URL con el Blob anterior */
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
    }
}
```

Podría hacerse en una única línea de código, pero para que comprendas el funcionamiento he desglosado cada uno de los pasos almacenando los resultados intermedios.

Para hacer uso de esta clase podemos modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
var facturaImpresa = this.impresionFacturaService
.ImprimirFactura(this.envioImpresion)
.subscribe(res => {
    if (res) {
        this.facturaDocumento = '';
        for (let registro of res) {
            this.facturaDocumento += registro.LINE;
        }
        /* Creamos una instancia de nuestra clase */
        var hexa = new DecodificarHexa(
            this.facturaDocumento,
            'application/pdf'
        );
        /* Usamos la propiedad URL generada */
        window.open(hexa.url);
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Puedes ver este código funcionando en el siguiente repositorio de github:

- https://github.com/ojgarciab/javascript-hex2pdf

Y comprobar el funcionamiento en línea en la siguiente página:

- https://ojgarciab.github.io/javascript-hex2pdf/